# Any tool to test SQL Server Stored Procs when data is not available in the database.

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, tdd, tsqlt

Are you aware of any utility or tool which tests sql server stored procedures where data is not available in the database, may be that tool should insert data into DB by reading the stored procedure...

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Testing without data is.... artificial. Slightly less artificial, you can use tools like "Data Dude" (aka Visual Studio Database Edition) to create large amounts of fake data based on a range of patterns and algorithms, and generate test code for your stored procedures (obviously just stubs - you need to add the actual tests yourself). Of course, you can also generate simulated data manually, or *depending on the environment* you may be able to do testing on a snapshot of the production data (obviously this depends on a: the production data *existing*, and b: security / data protection issues that may apply to your context).

Comment: I'd say "pointless" not "artificial"... unless you're testing basic syntax

Comment: @gbn and indeed the DB will usually reject basic syntax errors automatically

Answer (score 2):

If you use the tSQLt framework (http://tsqlt.org) you can insert data in the test for the purpose of the test, and this will be rolled back at the end so you don't affect the state of your database, if this is what you're concerned about.

tSQLt is also free and open source, which is another bonus.